# Bernoulli's outcome and the others - what's the difference?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I saw this in my textbook :

> Suppose now that n independent trials, each of which results in a
> success with probability p and in a failure with probability 1 − p,
> are to be performed. If X represents the number of successes that
> occur in the n trials, then X is said to be a binomial random variable
> with parameters (n, p). Thus, a Bernoulli random variable is just a
> binomial random variable with parameters (1, p). The probability mass
> function of a binomial random variable having parameters (n, p) is
> given by
> $$p(i) = \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{i-1} ~~~~~~~~~i = 0,1,...,n~~~~~~~~ (6.2)$$

My problem is why $6.2$  formula cant be used for below problem:

**Suppose one dice is rolled . What's the probability of seeing 2?**

I know that correct answer is $\frac{1}{6}$ .But according to last explanation , the probability would be :$$(\frac{1}{6})(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})$$
Why this could not happen ? what's the difference?

Comment: One roll of a d6 has $n=1$, not $n=6$. The $n$ is the number of rolls not the number of sides. So the "binomial(1,1/6)" PMF gives you ${1 \choose 1} (1/6)^1 (5/6)^0=(1/6)$.